# Error in wcf service

Tags: c#, wcf

I am using a wcf service to provide some data to my clients to plot a graph .I have seen some thing and created the service But when I run it is showing following error.How to over come it?
`The type 'WcfService2.Servi', provided as the Service attribute value in the`ServiceHost`directive, or provided in the configuration element`system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations`could not be found`.

this is my web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>

    <services>

      <service name="WcfService2.Servi" behaviorConfiguration="WcfService1.Service1Behavior">
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfService2.Servi" behaviorConfiguration="web" bindingConfiguration="crossDomain">

          <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.
          -->
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>

        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WcfService1.Service1Behavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>

      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="crossDomain" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
      </webHttpBinding>

    </bindings>

  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: sorry steve In fast I have posted that..Can you understand the question now?

Comment: There is still no question here.

Comment: ohh thats fine I have edited that once again .can you please check that. I have mentioned my error there.

Comment: Is your service contract type really called `WcfService2.Servi`?

Comment: Ya I have done a stupid thing forgot to change the name of namespace..thats why this stuff..

Comment: I've added this as an answer. If this solves your problem, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Your service contract type is called `WcfService2.Servi`. This looks like a typo. If you correct this, does the service work?